# PUT request results in 403 Forbidden - Need Apache to allow PUT requests

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I am building a RESTFUL API and need to get Apache to accept PUT requests. Whenever I put to a URL, I am getting a `403 Forbidden` error.

```
curl -X PUT api.example.com/api/foo
```

I have tried to add the following to my Virtual Directory (To no avail):

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

What other config settings might be causing this?

**EDIT**

I am re-writing my URL's, all get re-written to index.php as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the .htaccess file in this folder

-- For Apache 2.2

```
<Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS DELETE PATCH HEAD>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS DELETE PATCH HEAD>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

-- For Apache 2.4

```
<Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS DELETE PATCH HEAD>
    Require all granted
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS DELETE PATCH HEAD>
    Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
```

Note: you can remove methods which you dont want

Comment: Are you certain your  [`Require`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require) Directive syntax was already valid for Apache 2.2 (see the tag in the question) because as far as I know  `Require all` was introduced with [Apacge 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

Comment: Works great in centos7 / Apache 2.4 / Prestashop webservices context, since some methods are forbidden by default (it wasn't in 2.2/Debian).
@HBruijn : Limit and LimitExcept are in the official Apache 2.2 documentation, so it should also work with the adapted syntax (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#limit).

Comment: Perfect, That worked for me on Centos7

Answer (score 3):

At least with the last Apache's version (2.4.38) with modsecurity enabled, only these methods are allowed by default: GET HEAD POST OPTIONS

When a PUT request is made the error log of Apache2 returns this message:

```
[Wed May 06 11:46:56.680835 2020] [:error] [pid 20162] [client 172.16.x.x:58147] [client 172.16.12.144] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_methods}" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "46"] [id "911100"] 
[msg "Method is not allowed by policy"] [data "PUT"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.1.0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/RE1"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "192.168.x.x"] [uri "/app/api/widgets/grid"] [unique_id "XrKHkEqec4EieQ@yCDCkkQAAABI"], referer: https://192.168.x.x/app
```

The best way to solve it is changing this policy in modsecurity, so edit the file "**/etc/modsecurity/crs/crs-setup.conf**" and uncomment the following lines adding PUT as allowed:

```
SecAction \
"id:900200,\
phase:1,\
nolog,\
pass,\
t:none,\
setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=GET HEAD POST OPTIONS PUT DELETE'"
```

Comment: Thank you, this led my to the issue. I would never have thought for the modsecurity module

Comment: This helped me as well. Along with this post in cpanel https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/modsecurity-update-causing-403-forbidden-for-put-requests-to-server-requires-editing-tx-allowed_methods.683113/post-2810641

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Add this to your Apache conf:

```
 Script PUT /api/index.php
```

This assumes your actual handler script is called `index.php` and it's located on `/api`.

Comment: I updated my post with the mod_rewrite info, if I make the PUT request directly to the PHP script it returns 403 as well.

Comment: Sounds like Apache's allowing the request just fine, but the PHP is spitting out the 403.

Comment: What @Shane said. Can you GET it?

Comment: Yes, GET and POST work fine. Could it be PHP even though the error page being served is Apache's?

Comment: I think I was wrong - try making the change in my edit.